# change stylesheet using jquery when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code

```
<form action="creatPro.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="okk" value="agree" id="okk" onClick="EnableSubmit (this)" />agree
    <br />

    <center>
        <input type="submit" name="startthis" value="agree" disabled id="startthis" class="styled-button-8" />
    </center>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and this is my `javascript` code

```
EnableSubmit = function (val) {
    var sbmt = document.getElementById("startthis");

    if (val.checked == true) {
        sbmt.disabled = false;
    } else {
        sbmt.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

when the `checkbox` is checked the following action should be done :

> - enable the button `submit`
> - change the button color to blue for example

how can I change the button color using `Jquery` when it enabled ?

this is what I'm tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").checked(function(){
    $("input[type=submit]").css({"background-color":"blue"});
  });
});
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/noha/Ev2cc/4/)

Comment: yes I tried and I will post it now sorry ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery, you can do:

```
$('#okk').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#startthis').css('background-color','blue').prop('disabled', false);

    } else {
        $('#startthis').css('background-color','#ccc').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ev2cc/9/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#startthis").css({"background-color":"blue"});
```

**Or**

```
$("#startthis").css( "background-color", "blue" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `jQuery` to your `fiddle` Add it as a library to your `fiddle` and add the following line to your `EnableSubmit` function:

```
$('#startthis').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Comment: Note that changing the 'color' property will change the color of the button text, whereas changing the 'background-color' property changes the color of the button itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply :checked selector in your css for this purpouse

```
#startthis:checked{background-color:blue;}
#startthis{background-color:white;}
```